# If/Then Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$data = $con->query("SELECT id, content FROM table1 WHERE id IN (". $column['data'] .")");
```

I've got the code above that I need to add an if then statement to.

```
if table1.draftid = 0, then select content from table 1
if table1.draftid != 0, then select content from table 2
```

> Just for reference....
>   IF TABLE1.DRAFTID != 0, then `table1.draftid = table2.id`

I tried the following..

```
$data = $con->query("SELECT table1.id,

(case 
when table1.draftid = 0 then table1.content
when table1.draftid != 0 then (select table2.content from table2 where table1.draftid = table2.id) 
end) as data,


FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.draftid = table2.id 
WHERE table1.id IN (". $column['data'] .")");
```

### Example of use

```
> Table 1
>
>id = 1
>
>draftid = 1
>
>content = Table 1 Test

---------

> Table 2
>
> id = 1
>
> content = Table 2 Content
```

---

> The desired results: `If table 1 draftid = 0`, then it would call the
>   content from table 1.  BUT, if `table1.draftid != 0` (In example: 1), >then it would pull the content from table 2 where `table1.draftid = table2.id`

Comment: Is the two tables identical?

Comment: Unable to execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM data_table

Comment: @JorgeCampos no, they aren't.  But I thought that only mattered if you were selecting all columns using *?

Comment: No error anymore.  That was the error because as data had an , after it.  The error is gone, but content isn't being pulled.

Comment: Why use another when that is the opposit of the first? use ELSE

Comment: @sagi Just trying to figure it out.  Not perfected code lingo yet.  I'm just trying to actually get it to pull data.

Comment: Can you show a sample data from the two tables, so we can understand why it is not pulling the data? Add just a small sample and what would be the desired result.

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did the best I could in the last edit of my question.  There really is no specific data to show.  I am just trying to figure this code out before I can implement it and add the database of data.

Comment: The answer from @Madhivanan seems to be right. What is `$column['data']` returning? It may be filtering the results you need.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ....where it pulls table1.id = 1, table1.id = 2, table1.id = 3 etc.,....its checking to see if table1.id is in that series of numbers.

Comment: Since you are using a JOIN is it possible that the corresponding item from this list is not present in table2 ? is the only way I see it not returning the data. you have table1.id = 1 and not having this table2.id=1

Comment: that is correct.  Is there a better way than using join?

Comment: Fixed it.  LEFT JOIN and fixed a typo (had to change `as data` to `as content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$data = $con->query("SELECT table1.id,

(case 
when table1.draftid = 0 then table1.content
when table1.draftid != 0 then  table2.content
end) as data,


FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.draftid = table2.id 
WHERE table1.id IN (". $column['data'] .")");
```

Comment: Didn't work.  Its not pulling data from either table.

Comment: Thats seems to be what you need, a simple join between the table returns data? @KDJ

Comment: I think the issue is coming in with the JOIN.  The data on table1 and table2 is different.  Not all of the id's are in both tables.  Can join be replaced?

Comment: Fixed it.  LEFT JOIN and fixed a typo (had to change `as data` to `as content`